# Rails subset select always returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to search a dataset for a value.  If the dataset contains the value, the app does something.  If it does not, the app does something else.

The data breaks down like this: I have affiliates and users, each with a HABTM relationship to the other.  I have a page where the user can sign up for affiliates, which are displayed as a group of checkboxes.

I want the checkboxes for all the affiliates a user has currently signed up for checked.

Here's the code for the view (in HAML)

```
- @affiliates.each do |a|
  %li
    %label{ :for => "affiliate_#{a.id}"}= a.name
    - if @current_user.affiliates.select{ |ua| ua.id == a.id }
      = check_box_tag "affiliate_list[#{a.id}]", 1, true, {:id => "affiliate_#{a.id}"}
    - else
      = check_box_tag "affiliate_list[#{a.id}]", 1, false, {:id => "affiliate_#{a.id}"}
```

This code always returning true, and thus, checks boxes, even if a user has not signed up for an affiliate.

I looked up the .select method, but I keep coming up with the form helper stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if @current_user.affiliates.include?(a)
```

Comment: @current_user.affiliates.select{ |ua| ua.id == a.id } returns [] at best which is not false...
so
@current_user.affiliates.select{ |ua| ua.id == a.id } == []
would be correct, but just looks plain ugly
and isn't rails all about beatiful code ;)